# How filter Ack or SYN packets

Tags: traffic-shaping

I am trying to create a traffic shaping by tc filters.

In this traffic shaping ,  I have two class's . one of them is to control user's traffic and other which has more bandwidth rate is to Ack or SYN packets.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle 1: root

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbit
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 20mbit

tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip prio 10 parent 1:0 u32 match ip 192.168.0.0/16 flowid 1:1
```

But I don't know how can filter Ack or SYN packets .

How can i do it ? tanks

Answer (score 2):

From what I learnt, the filtering features of `tc` aren't as flexible as the ones you can get with `iptables` (where you can specify filtering by SYN/ACK flag presence). You can use iptables to "mark" each packet using such filtering, then use let tc recognize those marks to classify & prioritize the packets.

See [this tutorial](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.fullnat.intro.html), especially paragraph 15.10.2, for an example setup using this technique.